# SELECT inside REPLACE to use with SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have following query to use in SSRS:

```
SELECT  
  INCIDENTSM1.INCIDENT_ID, 
  (select '  ' + 
     PROBSUMMARYM2.HPC_ASSIGNEE
   from probsummarym1
   join PROBSUMMARYM2 on PROBSUMMARYM1.NUMBER = PROBSUMMARYM2.NUMBER
   where incidentsm1.INCIDENT_ID = PROBSUMMARYM1.INCIDENT_ID
   for XML path('')
  ) as Incidents, 
INCIDENTSM1.OPEN_TIME, ...
```

Second select return following data:

```
UserName1(UserLogin1)  UserName2(UserLogin2)  ...
```

I need to get rid of all this user logins in brackets.

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to read IMHO, it would help if you reviewed/revised it a bit, and tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I did understood correct

```
SELECT  
  INCIDENTSM1.INCIDENT_ID, 
  (select '  ' + 
     STUFF(PROBSUMMARYM2.HPC_ASSIGNEE,CHARINDEX('(',PROBSUMMARYM2.HPC_ASSIGNEE),CHARINDEX(')',PROBSUMMARYM2.HPC_ASSIGNEE)-2,'')
   from probsummarym1
   join PROBSUMMARYM2 on PROBSUMMARYM1.NUMBER = PROBSUMMARYM2.NUMBER
   where incidentsm1.INCIDENT_ID = PROBSUMMARYM1.INCIDENT_ID
   for XML path('')
  ) as Incidents,
```

Comment: I have a problem using STUFF with SSRS: it adds "<Expr1></Expr1>" tags in report. While running it in Server Managemet Studio doesn't have same issue. Do I miss something?